Finding the graphics driver in use when there are two different graphics chips
On a Thinkpad P15s, there are two graphic chips:
$ neofetch --stdout | grep "OS\|Kernel\|CPU\|GPU"
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS x86_64 
Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic 
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i7-1165G7 (8) @ 1.000GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA Quadro T500 Mobile 
GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 

How could I know which one is actually in use by the system?
Because both lshw and lspci are telling me that both are in use...
$ lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:194 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: TU117GLM [Quadro T500 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:207 memory:bd000000-bdffffff memory:6040000000-604fffffff memory:6050000000-6051ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)

$ lspci -nnk | egrep -i --color 'vga|3d|2d' -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

If both can be "in use" how could the specify which one to use for any given software?
